# "network places" setup on two headless LAN servers

Tags: networking, headless, shared-folders, lan

On my local LAN, I have two headless Debian servers. On a desktop, I could use "network places" for accessing folders across LAN.

***My question:*** Is it possible and if so how do I use command line to let each of these headless servers see each other permanently (i.e., not a temporary ssh tunnel or a temporary scp across the network).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, "network places" accesses the SMB shared drives, so if you want to access the Debian servers from your Windows desktop you need to install [Samba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29) on both of them, and configure them according to your needs.

There's a large number of [distributed file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_systems#Distributed_file_systems) you can use to allow the servers to access each other's directories ("folders"). [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System_%28protocol%29) is maybe the oldest standard used for Unix systems. [Here](https://www.howtoforge.com/install_nfs_server_and_client_on_debian_wheezy) is a how to set it up on Debian.

You can also use for example [sshfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) to make let them see each other "semi-permanently" (it still uses ssh, but you don't notice it, and the connection stays open). That may be the easiest solution if ssh is already working.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Unfortunately there is no windows os here. It's just debian servers and a linux desktop. i was hoping to get the two debian servers to see each other without samba

Comment: Set NFS server on Debian server and share to your linux desktop as NFS client.When you didnt want to install samba server on Debian server.

Comment: If there's no Windows involved, I'd recommend against installing Samba anyway, because it's a poor match for the Linux filesystem. Use NFS or sshfs.